# Geodesics in compact subsets of $TM$?

Tags: differential-geometry, proof-explanation, riemannian-geometry

This part comes from Petersen's book in the chapter of Hopf–Rinow. I don't quite understand how compactness is relevant here.

> [image]
>
> [image]

Isn't this just a sole application of the theorem? What does compactness of $\hat{K}$ have to do with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The point is you can get an $\epsilon>0$ which works for every point in $\hat{K}$ simultaneously. The Existence theorem only gives the existence of an $\epsilon>0$ locally, you will need a way to get something global. If there are finitely many neighborhoods and epsilons this is not a problem, take the minimum.

Comment: Ah right the minimum.